# Changing properties of a specific cell in a JTable (in netbeans)

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I have looked at several methods to do this but could not successfully implement this. If somebody could explain or forward me to a simpler guide on how to set a DefaultTableCellRenderer.

I just need the code to take in a coordinate, and highlight or bold the text in that cell.

This is all the code related to making the table:

```
public void updateTable(){
        
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)this.TableOfCards.getModel();
        //model.setRowCount(0);
        String[][] tableData = new String[wordNumber][numColumns];
        for (int i=0; i<wordNumber; i++){
            for (int j=0;j<numColumns;j++){
                tableData[i][j]=terms2.get(j).get(i);
            }
        }
          /*  ArrayList<String> row = terms2.get(i);
            tableData[i] = row.toArray(new String[row.size()]);
        }
            */
        String[] colNames = {"term1","term2","term3","term4","term5"};


        model.setDataVector(tableData, colNames);
        Object [] row = new Object[5];
```

One of the problems I have experienced is that Netbeans initialises components automatically when dragged and dropped. Therefore where multiple people implement these features when creating and formatting a table through code I am less sure what and where to add code and which code I need. I have tinkered and made several classes as well to help with this; however either I got to syntax errors which my translator gave no useful messages or suggestions or nothing happened.

Sorry for this not being explained well; it is my first time asking a question here.

Thanks.

Comment: In the Oracle tutorial, [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), there's a whole section on Using Custom Renderers.  Start with Oracle's code examples and add tiny tiny bits of code, testing fully each bit, until you've worked out what you want to do.

Comment: *One of the problems I have experienced is that Netbeans...* - don't use the IDE to generate your code. You are spending time learning the IDE and not Java/Swing. The code will not be easily maintainable if you ever switch to a different IDE. Just use the IDE to help with organizing your classes and debugging. Create your own GUI forms manually so you are in full control of the code.